# Unconfirmed transaction for 6 days now. Please help

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have an unconfirmed transaction that has been sitting there for 6 days now. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

https://blockchain.info/tx/98d4fee15e8eab8b78237a7b2eda8c62aa7c43a2e157b09ed4ee5b944092da6d

Cheers

Hoowee

Comment: Hi there, the difference here is that I withdrew my coins through an exchange.  Their support is terrible and hence I was hoping I can get some assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [CPFP](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51481/how-to-issue-a-cpfp) to add a massive fee and get it mined.  Essentially, you spend the unconfirmed transaction in another transaction (to yourself for example) and just use a really big fee.  Eventually a miner will want to mine *both* to get the fees.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the fee used is 61sat/B, but now the regular fee is 301sat/B and priority is 317sat/B. So you have to wait until a miner takes your transaction and confirm. I have faced this issue many times and waited for days and weeks to get a single confirmation.

If you are in a hurry then try any tx-accelerator like [viaBTC](https://pool.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/) or [pushtx](https://pushtx.btc.com/).

Also, you can check the mempool to see how long it may take to confirm your transaction.

Mempool state by fee level

- [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/mempool-state-by-fee-level)
- [BTC.com](https://btc.com/stats/unconfirmed-tx)

Comment: Manu, can I use tx-accelerators if the transfer was done via an exchange not my own wallet?

Comment: You only need a transaction ID. But use free accelerators, I would recommend you to wait for few more days. Be patient!!, it will be confirmed soon :)

Comment: Lol I've been waiting for 6 days. But ok I will take your advice and wait a couple more days.  Thank you Manu.