# My bitcoin core transaction is stuck in the mempool. I am the sender. I need help with either accelerating this transaction or preparing a CPFP trx

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool, replace-by-fee, child-pays-for-parent

Hello and thank you for looking at my first question. This is my first question ever on StackExchange.

I engaged in Bitcoin transactions as the sender; trying to send some Bitcoin to my CashApp so I could sell it and pay a few bills. On 05/26/23 at 23:38 I engaged in the following as the sender:

```
Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
Date: 5/26/23 23:38
To: Cashapp $GGVitt bc1qzk2pwzgs67pvv5dc63g6puxem68ykh4uj0w4dx
Debit: -0.00199859 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00000141 BTC
Net amount: -0.00200000 BTC
Transaction ID: 15917a30773ee3632883f6605d526329de41390422fe615b46c9482625c30a81
Transaction total size: 222 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 141 bytes
Output index: 0
```

Please note that this transaction does not have Replace-by-fee (RBF) enabled.

After doing some research, I came to the conclusion that I would need to create a Child-pays-parent-fees (herein, CFPF) transaction or use an accelerator service such as this: [ViaBTC|Transaction Accelerator](https://www.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator). Here is my [initial Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/13y0o7e/comment/jmlp495/?context=3) where I asked for help and obtained the conclusions I would have to either do CFPF

I am not sure at all how I would go about doing a CPFP transaction. I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/jkw0l5/transaction_stuck_read_this/) also on Reddit explaining a high-level-overview of what needs to be done; however, if possible I would appreciate a more detailed response as this would be my first ever CPFP transaction. I am not in a dire hurry to get these funds, its not life or death, but I would like to have the Bitcoin within a few months.

Also, here is the text of a few other transactions I have made after the initial one on 05/26/23 that may impact this. Again, I am not sure at all, but here is all the information I have and was able to research.

Thank you all so much.

Love, Vittorrio

PLEASE NOTE that some of the transactions (the ones I've bumped) have RBF enabled and are not going through, I believe this has something to do with my question; but I'm not sure. I've included a screenshot of my transactions tab in Bitcoin Core.

Here is the text export of my transaction list

```
"Confirmed","Date","Type","Label","Address","Amount (BTC)","ID"
"false","2023-06-02T07:55:01.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03904962","1014e8ca82ada04e15f21fc6d0e1e6a7fdaf00a0dab09730251c382fa59f532f"
"false","2023-06-01T23:22:01.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03903242","ba7d2617a4d26c7e40cab9aedbb4158d78a276aae0a1d6329d5fbadae1fb10b7"
"false","2023-06-01T23:21:32.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03901522","0b6ccd522bbb89f62ea044b74595be1d2608e070561ae6f8f05a98d8a22779cc"
"false","2023-06-01T23:21:22.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03899802","730d52624571f180e9c437a41c3ea2de23b541ddd4993022b6f94138a39e7fd0"
"false","2023-06-01T23:21:07.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03898082","c1cb3d86bac5ef374199302fb1f234b8ce6b47bb7f155c802337a9f6e4f4603f"
"false","2023-06-01T23:20:54.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03896362","5bb477069e2af33f3e6961e5c66a43accabaa4ac8c0cb099a6d7ce2d56ca7982"
"false","2023-06-01T23:20:44.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03894642","942ccd245c1f4c5f5b8737248a4440715899dc86eb8f83492a134bb8a3027833"
"false","2023-06-01T23:19:51.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03892922","6d64acdc3eeaa30614690d6efe0d3050bdd97b973c54538e4b460335875f6941"
"false","2023-06-01T23:18:38.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03891202","07fcadfbfe8a1c84005a4d4ece8bd9ed09b4efcd7c5cfe5166271c9cfa91c2f5"
"false","2023-06-01T23:18:18.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03889482","073f3a6cfdf4d5c6544635c8d965714d614a044cfc0505f7c491000a1092897e"
"false","2023-06-01T23:18:01.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03887762","93b9195d8c75482c48d2393d8601d35248e8550c89b1aa9db2525e8b4c2ec132"
"false","2023-06-01T23:17:43.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03886042","23addaf9876b324a04847b1836ebb89672147ee7f3fee176c46be57b4b925771"
"false","2023-06-01T23:17:23.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03884322","5d6e66c621561812cdcbab0dc22b96b768da7a9d5fa802cb7b538c9af9b9a565"
"false","2023-06-01T23:16:17.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03882602","da56a375e1a2304a2e18696d4154b2918361acf4202968467a689bbbe0992769"
"false","2023-06-01T23:15:55.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03880882","03a29f22119f6dc840150229a21c6832cdcb1f81f11678f02d7070f668933763"
"false","2023-06-01T23:15:21.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03879162","f6f0320806ea6061424c272c4ce7bbed14c7d0f433867ebf397630a6ac212977"
"true","2023-06-01T23:10:15.000","Received with","","bc1q7yv9m7lrtum4g3mz24d9ejh6ul0gkme4r3xuhd","0.00179763","59fc48841c0a8ce117b48860a2ecba765f0a3ae9eebf7679edaa3cb93d6b1a65"
"false","2023-06-01T21:34:33.000","Sent to","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv","-0.03872667","9e2384d0ccbe5bea72b59389ea2bd44f57935cce3d85a41afb6b90d0a7bcd451"
"false","2023-06-01T17:45:04.000","Sent to","Cashapp $GGVitt","bc1qzk2pwzgs67pvv5dc63g6puxem68ykh4uj0w4dx","-0.02500000","83e37a91c9e0ec16d6966b14a7c091b996e667322b2f895d96d2b01f07fb77ea"
"true","2023-06-01T17:36:34.000","Sent to","Cashapp $GGVitt","bc1qzk2pwzgs67pvv5dc63g6puxem68ykh4uj0w4dx","-0.00200000","e12f611db96874398488479bbf5f6053488108810cb7eef0bf17133cd1119b7d"
"true","2023-05-29T14:50:20.000","Received with","Example to show Tina","bc1qs9j7fge9m5gy82p2eynsjmltsdns524hmq7zfa","0.00028794","5b39a613943e07c212270c568166b5589349632a19f3d7fe7d91efeaf8473b14"
"true","2023-05-28T21:23:47.000","Received with","Misc Deposits","bc1qa5nvenwslkfyykjg6rhfjec9hkreteh8z9gu8x","0.00689790","9b9da8cb3f01458264fb00fb8f2f5aaf21d9797cb060ec5c56c9bcd103d23b1d"
"false","2023-05-26T23:38:26.000","Sent to","Cashapp $GGVitt","bc1qzk2pwzgs67pvv5dc63g6puxem68ykh4uj0w4dx","-0.00200000","15917a30773ee3632883f6605d526329de41390422fe615b46c9482625c30a81"
"true","2023-05-26T22:05:15.000","Received with","Genesis","bc1qjr6gm49mcz3ds7zt9wr4xxuv47hqfysr88u2hl","0.06054083","ce48b97cf248ef72378c92e7830e5a553e1af06724f2f85fc1f1d48e68685fba"
```

[image: transaction_list]

```
Status: 981 confirmations
Date: 5/26/23 22:05
From: unknown
To: bc1qjr6gm49mcz3ds7zt9wr4xxuv47hqfysr88u2hl (own address, label: Genesis)
Credit: 0.06054083 BTC
Net amount: +0.06054083 BTC
Transaction ID: ce48b97cf248ef72378c92e7830e5a553e1af06724f2f85fc1f1d48e68685fba
Transaction total size: 6416 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 6335 bytes
Output index: 105

Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
Date: 5/26/23 23:38
To: Cashapp $GGVitt bc1qzk2pwzgs67pvv5dc63g6puxem68ykh4uj0w4dx
Debit: -0.00199859 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00000141 BTC
Net amount: -0.00200000 BTC
Transaction ID: 15917a30773ee3632883f6605d526329de41390422fe615b46c9482625c30a81
Transaction total size: 222 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 141 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 675 confirmations
Date: 5/28/23 21:23
From: unknown
To: bc1qa5nvenwslkfyykjg6rhfjec9hkreteh8z9gu8x (own address, label: Misc Deposits)
Credit: 0.00689790 BTC
Net amount: +0.00689790 BTC
Transaction ID: 9b9da8cb3f01458264fb00fb8f2f5aaf21d9797cb060ec5c56c9bcd103d23b1d
Transaction total size: 12368 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 9157 bytes
Output index: 86

Status: 556 confirmations
Date: 5/29/23 14:50
From: unknown
To: bc1qs9j7fge9m5gy82p2eynsjmltsdns524hmq7zfa (own address, label: Example to show Tina)
Credit: 0.00028794 BTC
Net amount: +0.00028794 BTC
Transaction ID: 5b39a613943e07c212270c568166b5589349632a19f3d7fe7d91efeaf8473b14
Transaction total size: 6970 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 6889 bytes
Output index: 124

Status: 113 confirmations
Date: 6/1/23 17:36
To: Cashapp $GGVitt bc1qzk2pwzgs67pvv5dc63g6puxem68ykh4uj0w4dx
Debit: -0.00191312 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00008688 BTC
Net amount: -0.00200000 BTC
Transaction ID: e12f611db96874398488479bbf5f6053488108810cb7eef0bf17133cd1119b7d
Transaction total size: 222 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 141 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 17:45
To: Cashapp $GGVitt bc1qzk2pwzgs67pvv5dc63g6puxem68ykh4uj0w4dx
Debit: -0.02493110 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00006890 BTC
Net amount: -0.02500000 BTC
Transaction ID: 83e37a91c9e0ec16d6966b14a7c091b996e667322b2f895d96d2b01f07fb77ea
Transaction total size: 222 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 141 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 21:34
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00011817 BTC
Net amount: -0.03872667 BTC
Transaction ID: 9e2384d0ccbe5bea72b59389ea2bd44f57935cce3d85a41afb6b90d0a7bcd451
Transaction total size: 487 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 245 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 72 confirmations
Date: 6/1/23 23:10
From: unknown
To: bc1q7yv9m7lrtum4g3mz24d9ejh6ul0gkme4r3xuhd (own address)
Credit: 0.00179763 BTC
Net amount: +0.00179763 BTC
Transaction ID: 59fc48841c0a8ce117b48860a2ecba765f0a3ae9eebf7679edaa3cb93d6b1a65
Transaction total size: 7008 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 6846 bytes
Output index: 30

Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
Date: 6/2/23 07:55
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00044112 BTC
Net amount: -0.03904962 BTC
Transaction ID: 1014e8ca82ada04e15f21fc6d0e1e6a7fdaf00a0dab09730251c382fa59f532f
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:15
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00018312 BTC
Net amount: -0.03879162 BTC
Transaction ID: f6f0320806ea6061424c272c4ce7bbed14c7d0f433867ebf397630a6ac212977
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:15
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00020032 BTC
Net amount: -0.03880882 BTC
Transaction ID: 03a29f22119f6dc840150229a21c6832cdcb1f81f11678f02d7070f668933763
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:16
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00021752 BTC
Net amount: -0.03882602 BTC
Transaction ID: da56a375e1a2304a2e18696d4154b2918361acf4202968467a689bbbe0992769
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:17
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00023472 BTC
Net amount: -0.03884322 BTC
Transaction ID: 5d6e66c621561812cdcbab0dc22b96b768da7a9d5fa802cb7b538c9af9b9a565
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:17
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00025192 BTC
Net amount: -0.03886042 BTC
Transaction ID: 23addaf9876b324a04847b1836ebb89672147ee7f3fee176c46be57b4b925771
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:18
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00026912 BTC
Net amount: -0.03887762 BTC
Transaction ID: 93b9195d8c75482c48d2393d8601d35248e8550c89b1aa9db2525e8b4c2ec132
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:18
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00028632 BTC
Net amount: -0.03889482 BTC
Transaction ID: 073f3a6cfdf4d5c6544635c8d965714d614a044cfc0505f7c491000a1092897e
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:18
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00030352 BTC
Net amount: -0.03891202 BTC
Transaction ID: 07fcadfbfe8a1c84005a4d4ece8bd9ed09b4efcd7c5cfe5166271c9cfa91c2f5
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:19
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00032072 BTC
Net amount: -0.03892922 BTC
Transaction ID: 6d64acdc3eeaa30614690d6efe0d3050bdd97b973c54538e4b460335875f6941
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:20
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00033792 BTC
Net amount: -0.03894642 BTC
Transaction ID: 942ccd245c1f4c5f5b8737248a4440715899dc86eb8f83492a134bb8a3027833
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:20
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00035512 BTC
Net amount: -0.03896362 BTC
Transaction ID: 5bb477069e2af33f3e6961e5c66a43accabaa4ac8c0cb099a6d7ce2d56ca7982
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:21
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00037232 BTC
Net amount: -0.03898082 BTC
Transaction ID: c1cb3d86bac5ef374199302fb1f234b8ce6b47bb7f155c802337a9f6e4f4603f
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:21
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00038952 BTC
Net amount: -0.03899802 BTC
Transaction ID: 730d52624571f180e9c437a41c3ea2de23b541ddd4993022b6f94138a39e7fd0
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool, abandoned
Date: 6/1/23 23:21
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00040672 BTC
Net amount: -0.03901522 BTC
Transaction ID: 0b6ccd522bbb89f62ea044b74595be1d2608e070561ae6f8f05a98d8a22779cc
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 1

Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 6/1/23 23:22
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00042392 BTC
Net amount: -0.03903242 BTC
Transaction ID: ba7d2617a4d26c7e40cab9aedbb4158d78a276aae0a1d6329d5fbadae1fb10b7
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 0

Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
Date: 6/2/23 07:55
To: bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv bc1q56yetv4jhpkkcz32k25rmwnkhequjz09dss9fv
Debit: -0.03860850 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00044112 BTC
Net amount: -0.03904962 BTC
Transaction ID: 1014e8ca82ada04e15f21fc6d0e1e6a7fdaf00a0dab09730251c382fa59f532f
Transaction total size: 666 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 344 bytes
Output index: 0
```

[image: Bitcoin Core Overview]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to issue a CPFP?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51481/how-to-issue-a-cpfp)

Comment: It would be helpful to ask a specific question. A clearly stated question would be very helpful.